# Why does React throws an error if my context is used in my custom hook for getting data from Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I'm attempting to move my data fetching to custom hooks off of the component file for better code organization and I'm having issues with the hook not working when used in conjunction with my context.

This is my AuthContext.tsx file

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase.config';

export const UserContext = createContext<any>({});

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<unknown | null>({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
        });

        return () => {
            unsub();
        };
    }, []);

     return <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

This is my useRooms.ts file (my hook)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, QueryDocumentSnapshot, DocumentData } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { db } from '../firebase.config';
import { UserContext } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { RoomsResult } from './types';

export default function useRooms(): RoomsResult {
const [userRooms, setUserRooms] = React.useState<string[] | null>(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

const { currentUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);

const userRoomsQuery = query(collection(db, 'rooms'), where('user', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid));

const fetchUserRoomsData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const userRoomsDocs = await getDocs(userRoomsQuery);
    setUserRooms(userRoomsDocs.docs.map((doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => doc.id));
    setIsLoading(false);
};

console.log(userRooms);

return { rooms: userRooms, loading: isLoading, fetchUserRoomsData };
}
```

The error I recieve is:

[image]

As for those file names seen in the error they are all from my App.tsx file here

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from './context/AuthContext';
import { SignUpForm, LogInForm, ChatRooms } from './components/exporter';

type Styles = {
    wrapper: string;
};

function App() {
    const styles: Styles = {
         wrapper:
            'bg-purple-200 h-[100vh] w-[100vw] grid grid-cols [minmax(100px,_250px)_1fr_minmax(150px,_250px)] grid-rows-[85%_minmax(50px,_350px)] absolute',
    };

    const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }: any) => {
        if (!currentUser) {
            return <Navigate to="/login" />;
        } else return children;
    };

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                        <ProtectedRoute>
                            <div id="portal-container">
                                <ChatRooms />
                            </div>
                        </ProtectedRoute>
                    }
                ></Route>
                <Route path="login" element={<LogInForm />} />
                <Route path="signup" element={<SignUpForm />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The hook itself works as long as I do not use the line `const { currentUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);` inside the useRooms.ts file, but soon as I do I receive the error in picutre. **I place the use of the custom Hook useRooms inside of my <ChatRooms/> component which can be seen is rendered as the most nested element in App.tsx.** Any idea as to what is causing this and why ?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing. The image you included only includes some messaging about where the error was found. You might want to also type your `UserContext` context value, and many other that have `any` as their type. You are using Typescript, but you are not ***really*** using Typescript.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your feedback. I am making this project while learning to use Typescript hence the amount of 'any' you see around. I am now refactoring and going back to type check everything now that I understand Typescript better as I go which is why you see some stuff typed and others not.

The picture I uploaded is the only error that popped up then at the time so I'm not sure what else I was suppose to look at to get a more concise idea on the actual error. If you have pointers to give I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The error is usually output to the console right above the output that says, "the  above error occurred in the <ChatRooms> component: ...", so including what the *actual* error is/was is what would be relevant to include in the post. It also informs you that you should start your investigation in the `ChatRooms` component, which might also be a good thing to include in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by setting the default state of currentUser in AuthContextProvider to `null` instead of `{}`

Unfortunately this makes it so that when I refresh my web page it now forgets the logged in user. But this may be intended behavior until I check the Firebase Auth docs.